# Creating a pdf from a Word with excel: document.exportasfixedformat not creating the extension of the file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, pdf-generation

I'm using Excel vba, to modify a Word document and then save it as a pdf.  It runs smoothly, and it will create a pdf file, but it won't create the extension. So basically the problem is that the file is not recognize as a pdf (the icon is not a pdf icon)  and on open, it will ask for the application to use to open the file. On Windows explorer under "extension"  for this file there's a blank.
The portion of the code used to convert to pdf is:

```
Dim saved_successfull As Boolean
saved_successfull = False
Dim fenetre_saveas As Object
Set fenetre_saveas = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

With fenetre_saveas                     'save as pdf
  .InitialFileName = nom_complet
  .Title = "Confirmer le répertoire où le pdf sera sauvegardé"
  .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
  .FilterIndex = 25
  If .Show <> 0 Then
    worddoc.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    OutputFileName:=nom_complet, _
    ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, Openafterexport:=False
    saved_successfull = True
  End If
End With

If saved_successfull = True Then
    worddoc.Close savechanges:=False                                    'fermeture du doc word
    WordApp.Quit
    MsgBox ("Saved successfull")
    Exit Sub
Else
    MsgBox ("Couldn't convert in pdf")
End If

Exit Sub
```

So basically there's no error message generated.  I get the message box ("Saved succesfull"), the file is saved at the desired path with the right name.  But the extension of the file is not there.
So it's a pdf but it won't be automatically recognize as one.  If I use a pdf reader to open it, it will be read.
Any ideas, what am I missing?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The line

.InitialFileName = nom_complet

Contains the variable "nom_complet".  That variable needs to ends with ".pdf".  Although it's a pdf type the name of the file, if passed as a variable in the ".initialFileName" , must ends with ".pdf".

Okay, it was obvious, but maybe someone else will run into this problem, so I'll leave the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

add .pdf as a suffix to your filename and enclose in speech marks ie -

OutputFileName:="nom_complet.pdf"

your code amended below:

```
Dim saved_successfull As Boolean
saved_successfull = False
Dim fenetre_saveas As Object
Set fenetre_saveas = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

With fenetre_saveas                     'save as pdf
  .InitialFileName = nom_complet
  .Title = "Confirmer le répertoire où le pdf sera sauvegardé"
  .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
  .FilterIndex = 25
  If .Show <> 0 Then
    worddoc.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    OutputFileName:="nom_complet.pdf", _
    ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, Openafterexport:=False
    saved_successfull = True
  End If
End With

If saved_successfull = True Then
    worddoc.Close savechanges:=False                                    'fermeture du doc word
    WordApp.Quit
    MsgBox ("Saved successfull")
    Exit Sub
Else
    MsgBox ("Couldn't convert in pdf")
End If

Exit Sub
```